# Is it possible to output comments in Informatica Powercenter SQL Workbench messages pane?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am looking for the equivalent of system.out.println('blah blah') in PostgreSQL accessing Redshift.   I have a list of queries that run in a script and would like to see in the messages pane which query was running by giving it a name.

Comment: Could you explain how you're accessing Redshift? Does PostreSQL support `system.out.println()`? Or are you referring to your application which is talking to Redshift?

Comment: Apologies, If it made a difference, I mentioned Redshift.  That was all.  The SQL is PostgreSQL.  I run 10 or so queries in a script, I was just wondering if there was a way of Echo-ing out some text before each query ran.so I could see in the messages window which query was currently running.  I don't think it's possible, actually.